# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path by using retrofit & Gson

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

Here is my serivce interface:

```
@POST("/serachtracks")
Call<List<Track>> searchTracks(@Header("Authentification") String accessToken, @Query("tag") String tag);
```

Here is class Track:

```
public class Track implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("track_id")
public int id;

@SerializedName("track_title")
public String title;

@SerializedName("track_tags")
public String tags;

// ... GETERS & SERTERS
}
```

JSON that i receive from server:

```
[{"track_id":9833,"track_title":"A some title","track_tags":"#tags"}, {...}, {...}]
```

But i get this error:

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
                                                             at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:873)
                                                             at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826)
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380367/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-62

Comment: But I get from soundcloud the same JSON data and it works:

Comment: May be the problem in my server. My response from server looks like this:

Comment: `code $res = array(); for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) { $tracks = array( 'track_id' => 1, 'track_title' => 'ABC', 'track_tags' => 'tgs' ); array_push($res, $tracks); } header('Content-Type: application/json;'); echo json_encode($res);`

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was in my response from my server:**

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

is not good way.