# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path

Tags: android, gson

**My REsponse is,**

```
[
{
"category_name":"Vaporizers",
"categoryid":"3",
"status":"1",
"description":"<div class= bennar_out_div >\r\n<div class= container >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_left >\r\n<div class= viporizers_head >Vaporizers</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text1 >Whether you&rsquo;re looking for a portable or a desktop, GroovyVapes offers a wide variety of the highest quality vaporizers available. Every vaporizer that is part of the GroovyVapes lineup is thoroughly evaluated and tested and reviewed by our team to ensure its quality, design, and user-satisfaction.</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_right >FREE SHIPPING <span>over&nbsp;</span>&pound;85.00<br />NEWEST MODELS<br />PRIVATE &amp; SECURE</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div style= clear: both; >&nbsp;</div>",
"image":false,
"count":0,
"subcategory_name":[
{
"sub_category_name":"Portable",
"sub_categoryid":"10",
"status":"1",
"description":"<div class= bennar_out_div >\r\n<div class= container >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_left >\r\n<div class= viporizers_head >PORTABLE</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text1 >Portable Vaporizers are best used for vaping on the go. Most portable vaporizers are battery powered, with many being easily chargeable via USB.</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_right >FREE SHIPPING <span>over&nbsp;</span>&pound;85.00<br />NEWEST MODELS<br />PRIVATE &amp; SECURE</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div style= clear: both; >&nbsp;</div>",
"image":"http://www.groovyvapes.co.uk/media/catalog/category/portable.png",
"count":26
}}
]
```

**MyCode :**

```
ArrayList<BrandAccessoriesResponseModel> mBrandAccessoriesResponseModelArrayList = new ArrayList<BrandAccessoriesResponseModel>();

Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<BrandAccessoriesResponseModel>>() {}.getType();
            mBrandAccessoriesResponseModelArrayList = gson.fromJson(result.toString(), listType);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 62](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380367/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-62)

Answer (score 0):

Please review your code,  and calling API, again,  your code is correct, not required to change,,. Check your calling API ONCE AGAIN.

Answer (score 0):

A valid json should look like this:

```
    [
     {
      "category_name":"Vaporizers",
      "categoryid":"3",
      "status":"1",
      "description":"<div class= bennar_out_div >\r\n<div class= container >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_left >\r\n<div class= viporizers_head >Vaporizers</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text1 >Whether you&rsquo;re looking for a portable or a desktop, GroovyVapes offers a wide variety of the highest quality vaporizers available. Every vaporizer that is part of the GroovyVapes lineup is thoroughly evaluated and tested and reviewed by our team to ensure its quality, design, and user-satisfaction.</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_right >FREE SHIPPING <span>over&nbsp;</span>&pound;85.00<br />NEWEST MODELS<br />PRIVATE &amp; SECURE</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div style= clear: both; >&nbsp;</div>",
      "image":false,
      "count":0,
      "subcategory_name":
      [
          {
              "sub_category_name":"Portable",
              "sub_categoryid":"10",
              "status":"1",
              "description":"<div class= bennar_out_div >\r\n<div class= container >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text >\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_left >\r\n<div class= viporizers_head >PORTABLE</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text1 >Portable Vaporizers are best used for vaping on the go. Most portable vaporizers are battery powered, with many being easily chargeable via USB.</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class= viporizers_text_right >FREE SHIPPING <span>over&nbsp;</span>&pound;85.00<br />NEWEST MODELS<br />PRIVATE &amp; SECURE</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div style= clear: both; >&nbsp;</div>",
              "image":"http://www.groovyvapes.co.uk/media/catalog/category/portable.png",
              "count":26
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Now, using jsonschema2pojo: 
[jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org)

You can have the following:

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("category_name")
@Expose
private String categoryName;
@SerializedName("categoryid")
@Expose
private String categoryid;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private Boolean image;
@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private Integer count;
@SerializedName("subcategory_name")
@Expose
private List<SubcategoryName> subcategoryName = new ArrayList<SubcategoryName>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The categoryName
*/
public String getCategoryName() {
return categoryName;
}

/**
* 
* @param categoryName
* The category_name
*/
public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The categoryid
*/
public String getCategoryid() {
return categoryid;
}

/**
* 
* @param categoryid
* The categoryid
*/
public void setCategoryid(String categoryid) {
this.categoryid = categoryid;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The status
*/
public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

/**
* 
* @param status
* The status
*/
public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The description
*/
public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

/**
* 
* @param description
* The description
*/
public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The image
*/
public Boolean getImage() {
return image;
}

/**
* 
* @param image
* The image
*/
public void setImage(Boolean image) {
this.image = image;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The count
*/
public Integer getCount() {
return count;
}

/**
* 
* @param count
* The count
*/
public void setCount(Integer count) {
this.count = count;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The subcategoryName
*/
public List<SubcategoryName> getSubcategoryName() {
return subcategoryName;
}

/**
* 
* @param subcategoryName
* The subcategory_name
*/
public void setSubcategoryName(List<SubcategoryName> subcategoryName) {
this.subcategoryName = subcategoryName;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.SubcategoryName.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class SubcategoryName {

@SerializedName("sub_category_name")
@Expose
private String subCategoryName;
@SerializedName("sub_categoryid")
@Expose
private String subCategoryid;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private Integer count;

/**
* 
* @return
* The subCategoryName
*/
public String getSubCategoryName() {
return subCategoryName;
}

/**
* 
* @param subCategoryName
* The sub_category_name
*/
public void setSubCategoryName(String subCategoryName) {
this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The subCategoryid
*/
public String getSubCategoryid() {
return subCategoryid;
}

/**
* 
* @param subCategoryid
* The sub_categoryid
*/
public void setSubCategoryid(String subCategoryid) {
this.subCategoryid = subCategoryid;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The status
*/
public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

/**
* 
* @param status
* The status
*/
public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The description
*/
public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

/**
* 
* @param description
* The description
*/
public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The image
*/
public String getImage() {
return image;
}

/**
* 
* @param image
* The image
*/
public void setImage(String image) {
this.image = image;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The count
*/
public Integer getCount() {
return count;
}

/**
* 
* @param count
* The count
*/
public void setCount(Integer count) {
this.count = count;
}

}
```