# why i get null value when i parse JSON data from web service into android?

Tags: android, json, web-services

what i have is an asp web service which invoke for me the following JSON code :

```
[
  {
    "_OrderDetails": [
      {
        "ProductName": "FUCHS SUPER GT SAE 10W30 6X5 / FP10100010102",
        "TotalAfterDiscount_Lc": "7500",
        "MeasureUnitName": "كرتونة",
        "TotalPrice_Lc": "7500",
        "PricePerUnit_Lc": "75",
        "Quantity": "100"
      }
    ],
    "Id": "274",
    "OrderDate": "4/10/2014 12:00:00 AM",
    "Number": "16",
    "CustomerName": "الأسد",
    "Note": ""
  }
]
```

and i have created an entity (java class) like this :

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SerializedName("_OrderDetails")
    private OrderDetails[] mOrderDetails;

    @SerializedName("Id")
    private String mId;

    @SerializedName("OrderData")
    private String mOrderDate;

    @SerializedName("Number")
    private String mNumber;

    @SerializedName("CustomerName")
    private String mCustomerName;

    @SerializedName("Note")
    private String mNote;

    // Add setters and getters
    public String getOrderDate() {
        return mOrderDate;
    }
    public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
        mOrderDate = orderDate;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return mNumber;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        mNumber = number;
    }
    public String getNote() {
        return mNote;
    }
    public void setNote(String note) {
        mNote = note;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        mId = id;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return mCustomerName;
    }
    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        mCustomerName = customerName;
    }

    public static class OrderDetails implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @SerializedName("ProductName")
        private String mProductName;

        @SerializedName("TotalAfterDiscount_Lc")
        private String mTotalAfterDiscount;

        @SerializedName("MeasureUnitName")
        private String mMeasureUnitName;

        @SerializedName("TotalPrice_Lc")
        private String mTotalPrice;

        @SerializedName("PricePerUnit_Lc")
        private String mPricePerUnit;

        @SerializedName("Quantity")
        private String mQuantity;

        // Add setters and getters



        public String getProductName() {
            return mProductName;
        }
        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            mProductName = productName;
        }
        public String getTotalAfterDiscount_Lc() {
            return mTotalAfterDiscount;
        }
        public void setTotalAfterDiscount_Lc(String totalAfterDiscount_Lc) {
            mTotalAfterDiscount = totalAfterDiscount_Lc;
        }
        public String getMeasureUnitName() {
            return mMeasureUnitName;
        }
        public void setMeasureUnitName(String measureUnitName) {
            mMeasureUnitName = measureUnitName;
        }
        public String getTotalPrice_Lc() {
            return mTotalPrice;
        }
        public void setTotalPrice_Lc(String totalPrice_Lc) {
            mTotalPrice = totalPrice_Lc;
        }
        public String getPricePerUnit_Lc() {
            return mPricePerUnit;
        }
        public void setPricePerUnit_Lc(String pricePerUnit_Lc) {
            mPricePerUnit = pricePerUnit_Lc;
        }
        public String getQuantity() {
            return mQuantity;
        }
        public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
            mQuantity = quantity;
        }
    }
```

and in the main activity :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
 Item[] items = new Gson().fromJson(responseJSON, Item[].class);
 String date=items[0].getOrderDate();
 Log.e("data",date+"");
```

but it gives me null !! in the logcat so please can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: follow this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: could you check if `responseJSON` is filled? Like `Log.e("Response", responseJSON);`

Comment: yes i get all the data in the json response

Comment: the exception says JSON array can't be converted to JSON object !!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in the Java class you have created to map the JSON attributes. I had a similar problem too and I stumbled upon this awesome answer.

[Java Json program not showing any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019117/java-json-program-not-showing-any-output/16019784#16019784)

Have a look at it and hope it helps!